# When to use properties vs. plain ol' getters and setters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm just wondering about semantics. When is something truly a "property" of an object? I noticed in a lot of Apple's APIs, they explicitly define getters and setters instead of using properties (e.g. `URL` and `setURL` on `NSURLRequest`/`NSMutableURLRequest`; surely the URL seems like a "property" of an URL request, right?) I'm wondering if there's some subtle thing that I'm missing or if Apple just doesn't like properties all that much. =P

UPDATE: As of iOS 8, Apple has converted most (if not all) of their non-property getters and setters to properties. (Probably done so that Swift compatibility would be easier.)

Comment: Properties **are** setters and getters. There's no real difference.

Comment: I made my question clearer.

Comment: A lot of Apple's APIs predate the introduction of properties. Cocoa was around for about 6 years (and NextStep, on which it's based, for years before that) before the declared property functionality was added to ObjC.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but let's consider UIView. UIView has the method `constraints`. Why is that not a read-only property?

Comment: @JoshCaswell actually his question isn't clear... the title asks a question then he has ?'s in his description which is different.

Comment: It's clear to me, @Bot, and neither of the body nor the title ask "_how_ do I create a property", or "what does this syntax do?" This is a design question.

Comment: To understand a question you need 27K or more reputations :P

Comment: read http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial

Comment: `constraints` is a method rather than a property because it's a list, and access to the list is being mediated by other methods (`addConstraint:`, e.g.). The class doesn't want you setting the whole list, but it will let you inspect it.

Comment: But a read-only property achieves the same thing, no? What's the semantic difference between them?

Comment: Yes, that's true, a read-only property would have the same effect there. I suspect that came down to one individual person's momentary decision -- the "symmetry" of all access being through methods, perhaps? I can't provide any insight into that one.

Comment: Perhaps you're right (c.f. `constraints` vs. `gestureRecognizers`), although I'm still not satisfied. =P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> or if Apple just doesn't like properties all that much.

The real cause is that most of the Foundation framework (let's not forget you're talking about `NS*` classes) is old as dirt - they have been around there since the NeXT times... At that time, the Objective-C language didn't sport the `@property` keyword - to emulate properties, it was necessary for the programmers to declare and implement getter and setter methods manually, this applied to Apple's code as well.

Now the Foundation framework is so fundamental that it hasn't changed a lot. It hasn't been radically rewritten and as far as I'm concerned, programmers who wrote it didn't bother rewriting all the code using the new syntax. You can see that recently added classes do in fact feature declared properties instead of getters and setters, but that's not true for older classes.

Anyway, properties declared manually and those declared using `@property` and `@synthesize` are completely equivalent. That said, there's a very minor difference when accessing them, but that doesn't belong to the declaration thingy: if you write

```
someObject.someProperty
```

in your code, the `someObject` must have a complete and concrete type, so if a property named `someProperty` is nonexistent, you'll get a compiler error. In contrast,

```
[someObject someProperty]
```

and

```
[someObject setSomeProperty:]
```

allow you the method call even if it's undeclared.

**Edit:**

> I ask what the semantic difference between them is

So by "semantic difference", you meant "when it should be used" rather than "does it run differently". I see. Well... Conceptually, properties represent state. A property is a particular characteristic of an object that may change over time. It's just an unrelated fact that properties are accessed using accessor *methods* in Objecive-C.

If you write a method that acts on the obejct (other than setting a property, of course), there's a fair chance you should be declaring and calling it as a method. If you access (read or write) an attribute of an object, that better fits the task of a property.

Comment: See my comment to JoshCaswell above. Also, I already know that you can use properties and plain ol' getters and setters in the exact same way; however, I'm asking what the semantic difference between them is.

Comment: @fumoboy007 See the first sentence of the 3rd paragraph... >.<

Comment: @fumoboy007 Is it really necessary to downvote my answer because you failed to read it?

Comment: @fumoboy007: Are you more interested in why Apple doesn't use them, or why you should?

Comment: @JoshCaswell However, the question shows something else in fact. I answered the question... I can't help understanding stuff if even the akser doesn't know what he is interested in, finally...

Comment: @fumoboy007: The answer to the first is as H2CO3 and I have said, that they simply haven't rewritten the entirety of Foundation to use the new functionality. The second I don't feel like I have time to answer right now, but I'm sure someone will come along. In a sentence, properties are for state, and methods are for actions.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, I read that. Did you read the second sentence of my first comment on this answer?

Comment: @fumoboy007 You mean "however, I'm asking what the semantic difference between them is."? Sure. That's why I answered "properties declared manually and those declared using property and synthesize are completely equivalent."...

Comment: @JoshCaswell hmmm…that's interesting…state vs. actions

Comment: @H2CO3 No, I was referring to "Also, I already know that you can use properties and plain ol' getters and setters in the exact same way"; but I think I understand what you were saying now (it was kinda ambiguous because of the "completely equivalent" part). You should edit your answer so that I can remove my downvote.

Comment: @fumoboy007 Done, thanks. Next time please post two questions if you have two questions.

Comment: H2CO3 is correct in all of this, but one minor note: accessor declaration and properties and *almost* equivalent. They have one tiny difference. Things declared as properties will be returned by `class_copyPropertyList()`, while method-declared accessors will not. This is an incredibly small difference, but can occasionally matter if you're performing introspection. In the great scheme of ObjC, properties are pretty new, and since they overlap existing functionality, you will still see some minor inconsistencies in their use even among seasoned developers. And somewhat it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @RobNapier I should have put that in the answer. Actually, that's why I prefer using selectors while messing with reflection.

Comment: @H2CO3 Regarding properties representing state, so what happened with `constraints` vs. `gestureRecognizers` in `UIView`? Is it like JoshCaswell said – just some person's heat-of-the-moment decision?

Comment: @H2CO3 Also, I didn't realize I had two questions…

Comment: @fumoboy007 "just some person's heat of the moment decision?" - Pretty much yes, I suspect. This design question is **so marginal** that even Apple engineers don't dedicate that much attention to it.

Comment: @H2CO3 And now you know how OCD I am. =P

Answer (score 1):

Having a getter and setter lets you use messages to access the item

`[myObject someProperty]` or `[myObject setSomeProperty: someNewValue]`

Making something a `@property` gives you the additionally ability to use dot notation to call the getter and setter. This is because `@property` chooses method names that make the class key-value-coding compliant for the particular value.

`myObject.someProperty`  or `myObject.someProperty = someNewValue`

While it is possible to do this manually, it is considered best-practice to use `@property` when you want to use the dot notation.  Over time, the behind-the-scenes bahaviours of `@property` and `@synthesize` have changed quite a bit particularly in regard to auto-creating storage for the associated pointer.  Using `@property` makes it easier to keep up with Apple's changes in convention with little or no change in your code.

Additionaly, using `@property` makes your code much easier to read.

Comment: This is not correct. Both dot notation and bracket notation work whether the method was declared with a property or not. `myString.integerValue;` is perfectly valid, as is `[myUIViewController setEditing:YES];`

Comment: It is technically possible to use dot notation to call a method that has no parameters.  However, this is not considered best practice.  Furthermore, the dot notation will not work for the setter unless @property is used.

Comment: Yes, it most certainly will, as long as the setter follows the correct naming convention: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/27e15b25ac8996056d27 The point about best practice is true, however, and would probably be a good thing to bring up in answering this question.

Comment: Yes, if the methods you create are named such that they make the class key-value-coding compliant for the value in question, the getter and setter will work using dot-notation.  I will rephrase my answer.